# Loop Through DB, get table dependencies inquiry

Tags: t-sql, dependencies, ssms, database-cursor

Goal
Use Table Cursor to loop through all tables within schema and get table dependencies.

I want to use it like this

```
    DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @SchemaName = 'dbo'
    
    DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
    OPEN TableCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 
            '
            IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#temp'',''U'') IS NOT NULL
                DROP TABLE #temp;
            SELECT * INTO #temp FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(' + @SchemaName +'.'+ @TableName + ', ''OBJECT'')
            '
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
        FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
    END
    CLOSE TableCursor
    DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Tried

```
    DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @table = 'dbo.InventTable'
    SET @sql = 
        '
        SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(' + @table + ', ''OBJECT'')
        '
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Expecting
Just the result of sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzTry.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have some requirement to use a cursor, but it's typically not the best way to go, there are exceptions of course.

Instead, you can use `CROSS APPLY` with the function and pass in an object name derived from columns. This functions like an INNER JOIN (with the OUTER version being `OUTER APPLY`). In this case you'll get a 0-many response, joined to your existing data set.

```
SELECT t.name AS TableName, s.name AS SchemaName, QUOTENAME(s.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(t.Name) AS ObjectName,
       re.referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name, QUOTENAME(re.referencing_schema_name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(referencing_entity_name) AS ReferencingObjectName, 
       o.type_desc AS ReferencingObjectType
  FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
      ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(s.name+'.'+t.name, 'OBJECT') re
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o
      ON referencing_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s2
      ON re.referencing_schema_name = s2.name
 WHERE s.name = 'dbo'
 --AND t.Name = 'InventTable'
```

I left the table name commented out, so the query as it is will return rows for everything within the specified schema, but you could uncomment it to get specific. I also modified the columns to return to best fit what I think you wanted.

Comment: Patrick you are awesome. Thank you and this does serve my purpose!

Still wondering why cursor did not work .

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, Patrick Hurst's answer is the method I would use. It's faster, cleaner and less code..
If this was my question, I would mark that answer as the accepted one.

**However, if you MUST use a cursor then read on...**

```
DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
SET @SchemaName = 'dbo'

/* Create a temp table to store the results so it's available to the temp query'*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp(
    [mySchemaName] [sysname],
    [myTableName] [sysname],
    [referencing_schema_name] [sysname] ,
    [referencing_entity_name] [sysname] ,
    [referencing_id] [int] ,
    [referencing_class] [tinyint] ,
    [referencing_class_desc] [nvarchar](60) ,
    [is_caller_dependent] [bit]
    ) 

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 
        'INSERT INTO #temp SELECT  ''' + @SchemaName + ''', ''' + @TableName + ''', * FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(''' + @SchemaName +'.'+ @TableName + ''', ''OBJECT'')'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

The are three main differences between your original code and the modified version above.

1. The `#temp` table is created once before the loop so it can be referenced by the `sp_execuitesql` and therefore no need to drop it each time.
2. The dynamic sql does an `INSERT INTO #temp` as the #temp table will already exist
3. I've double quoted around the 'SchemaName.TableName' as the object name needs to be quoted in `dm_sql_referencing_entities`

Comment: Thank you for answering Alan! I understand and you saved me from the frustration in getting this to work :)

Comment: @AlanSchofield found all the issues, I think
A great way to start debugging this sort of of problem is to use `PRINT`. I commented out the `EXEC` line in your code, and added `PRINT @SQL` and ran it. You should be able to quickly see all of the points Alan made from there.